# Diagnose wifi problems

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

First of all sorry for any spelling errors i might have i'm using my tablet.
The problem is simple my wifi connection keeps dropping.

The wifi signal is full.

My home wifi works great this is from work.

I've restarted the router.

I've changed the channel from 6 to 8.

I have no static ip.

It works on my tablet and on other laptops.

It works when i plug a network cable.

I have a valid ip configuration.

I can't even connect to the router web interface.

I get request time out for about 90% of the ping to google.

The router is a Trendnet TEW-691GR, and i'm running Win8 x64 on a dell studio 1558 PP39L.

Thanks.

Comment: I've got quite the same problem over wifi connection, although wired works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open up command prompt. (Run -> cmd.exe)
Type the following:

1. ipconfig /flushdns
2. ipconfig /release
3. ipconfig /renew

Then try reconnecting to the network.